# Does Halo 2 in the The Master Chief Collection still have all the same super bounce glitches?

Tags: halo-the-master-chief-collection, halo-2

I fondly remember reading about the super bounce glitches in Halo 2 then hoarding the knowledge for my use only in LAN parties!

Keen to relive the Halo 2 experiences in HD, but do these same wonderful glitches (plus the rocket-sword glitch!) still exist in The Master Chief Collection?

Comment: I know Halo CE in MCC still has at least some of the "useful" glitches. I assume for Halo 2 they've kept them if possible.

Comment: @TZHX Sweet, that sounds like good news

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Halo wiki on Fandom](https://halo.fandom.com/wiki/Super_bouncing):

> Super bouncing is possible in the Classic mode of Halo: The Master Chief Collection, but not in the same niches that allowed super jumping in the original Halo 2 version.

The source they cite has a [list of setup videos for super bounces in The Master Chief Collection](http://teambeyond.net/halo-master-chief-collection-super-bounce-locations/).